containerd to use pause image from local container runtime?
My (lab/learning) Kubernetes cluster is running with containerd as a runtime (CRI).
By looking at /etc/containerd/config.toml I can see that containerd is pulling pause image from remote repository:
sandbox_image = "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8"

I want to tell contrainerd to use pause image which is already pulled to the local container runtime:
lab@master:~$ sudo crictl image
IMAGE                                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            SIZE
docker.io/calico/cni                      v3.26.0             5d6f5c26c6554       93.3MB
docker.io/calico/kube-controllers         v3.26.0             45ae357729e3a       33.8MB
docker.io/calico/node                     v3.26.0             44f52c09decec       87.6MB
registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns           v1.10.1             ead0a4a53df89       16.2MB
registry.k8s.io/etcd                      3.5.10-0            a0eed15eed449       56.6MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver            v1.28.7             eeb80ea665767       34.7MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager   v1.28.7             4d9d9de55f196       33.4MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy                v1.28.7             123aa721f941b       28.1MB
registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler            v1.28.7             309c26d006295       18.6MB
registry.k8s.io/pause                     3.8                 4873874c08efc       311kB   <-- here
registry.k8s.io/pause                     3.9                 e6f1816883972       322kB

I tried to modify sandbox_image in /etc/containerd/config.toml to the following:
sandbox_image = "pause:3.8"

But then containerd service failed to start:
Apr 05 21:49:20 master containerd[1803]: time="2024-04-05T21:49:20.386597952Z" level=info msg="StopPodSandbox for \"d100902f983a92cbf0f385d490fdec5917549c181c88f0287782f45d31f04226\""
Apr 05 21:49:20 master containerd[1803]: time="2024-04-05T21:49:20.389443313Z" level=info msg="Container to stop \"b6b0cbd161076fd52885b03ca55094535af3b2b86fa0d0412c47a4235ce46178\" must be in running or unknown state, current state \"CONTAINER_EXITED\""
Apr 05 21:49:20 master containerd[1803]: time="2024-04-05T21:49:20.392477900Z" level=info msg="TearDown network for sandbox \"d100902f983a92cbf0f385d490fdec5917549c181c88f0287782f45d31f04226\" successfully"
Apr 05 21:49:20 master containerd[1803]: time="2024-04-05T21:49:20.394401174Z" level=info msg="StopPodSandbox for \"d100902f983a92cbf0f385d490fdec5917549c181c88f0287782f45d31f04226\" returns successfully"
Apr 05 21:49:20 master containerd[1803]: time="2024-04-05T21:49:20.406690451Z" level=info msg="RunPodSandbox for &PodSandboxMetadata{Name:kube-scheduler-master,Uid:4043e87c9e9d5772c32e4050b11757a4,Namespace:kube-system,Attempt:22,}"
Apr 05 21:49:21 master containerd[1803]: time="2024-04-05T21:49:21.320155662Z" level=info msg="trying next host" error="pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed" host=registry-1.docker.io
Apr 05 21:49:21 master containerd[1803]: time="2024-04-05T21:49:21.330971667Z" level=error msg="RunPodSandbox for &PodSandboxMetadata{Name:kube-scheduler-master,Uid:4043e87c9e9d5772c32e4050b11757a4,Namespace:kube-system,Attempt:22,} failed, error" error="failed to get sandbox image \"pause:3.8\": failed to pull image \"pause:3.8\": failed to pull and unpack image \"docker.io/library/pause:3.8\": failed to resolve reference \"docker.io/library/pause:3.8\": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed"
Apr 05 21:49:21 master containerd[1803]: time="2024-04-05T21:49:21.332934072Z" level=info msg="stop pulling image docker.io/library/pause:3.8: active requests=0, bytes read=5069"

Question:
How can I configure contrainerd to use pause image from the local container runtime
UPDATE:
I have replaced pause:3.8 with it's ID 4873874c08efc and that worked.
Is there any reason why ID does work but name does not?
